# Get angle value in android studio in degree or radian

Tags: android, angle

I would like to get angle value of an android phone and write it to screen as degrees or radian. I have tried to get this information with the help of accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. However I couldn't convert the values to radian. Magnetometer shows the position of the phone in microTesla but I don't know how I can convert it to radian. Could you please guide me or propose some documentations that can show me how to get angle of phone in radian?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the accelerometer. When the phone is lying on a flat surface, the value should be around 9,81m/s², which is our gravity constant on Earth (at least on "normal" heights). When you rotate your phone 90 degrees, this will drop to 0m/s², as there is no gravity pulling the chip "sideways" (of course I am talking about the y sensor). When putting your phone screen down, the accelerometer will point out -9.81m/s². Now you can convert these values as they linaerely change with the rotation of your phone. Same goes for tilting your phone to the side, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked. I didn’t think to use gravity of Earth. After your response I divide y response of Accelerometer sensor and found cosinus of the angle.